# How to access deployed project in gcloud shell

Tags: django, gcloud

Deployed a `django project` in `gcloud` in `flexible environment` from local using `gcloud app deploy`.
The changes are getting reflected in the live url.

I am trying to access the deployed `django project` folder through `gcloud shell`, but not able to find it.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you used the google tutorials and their github code to deploy the Django Project on the cloud

Comment: @babygame0ver: yes

Comment: then you can get their code from their github page and then upload it back to the gcloud using the ssh shell that you are using from the browser

Comment: you can choose the one you used from here :-) https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform

Comment: @babygame0ver: but i have already deployed the project in gcloud. my qn is, how to access that folder in gcloud shell

Comment: actually when you type the deploy command then it is gone to particular server which is maintained by the google aka server configuration folder, but you can change the files before deploying the files into the gcloud. The thing to understand here is that you are using SAAS not PAAS where you just have to focus on the code and application without going into the server details , but if you want that then try vm instances than the app engine because it will give you full vm but all things you have to configure manually which is the true feature of the PAAS

Comment: IF you are using the app engine then I think you can only change the code and CA certificates of the project not more than that

Comment: Yup, i think the solution to my question is to switch to compute engine (IaaS), which gives better control over VM instance configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162258/discussion-between-babygame0ver-and-dreamer).

Answer (score 0):

Extended from discussion with @babygameover.

Google App Engine(GAE) is a PaaS. in GAE, one could just code locally and deploy the project, while the scaling of instances and its related resources would be taken care by gcloud.

And to have control over instances, the project should be moved into Google Compute Engine(GCE) where one would get finer control over instance configurations.